# Fit is different from analytic model used to sample data

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting

I am sampling responses which follow a Hill equation $E = E_0 + \frac{\mbox{Dose}\times\mbox{E}_{max}}{\mbox{Dose} + \mbox{ED}_{50}}$ where $E_0$ is the baseline effect, $\mbox{Dose}$ is the applied dosage, $\mbox{ED}_{50}$ is the dosage at which half maximum effect is achieved and $\mbox{E}_{max}$ is the maximum effect.

The parameters have the following values (arbitrary units):
$\mbox{E}_0 = 2$, $\mbox{ED}_{50} = 100$ and $\mbox{E}_{max} = 10$.

In the figure, I'm plotting the raw data, the analytic form of the parametrized function (blue) and a non-linear least squares fit (red).

Should not the blue and red lines virtually coincide since I'm fitting the function against data that was obtained using the same function?

[image]

The data basically comes from 'example2' from the [MSToolkit tutorial](http://mstoolkit.r-forge.r-project.org/data%20generation_%20examples.html).

---

Edit based on comment: **not** subtracting $\mbox{E}_0$ from the data, increasing samples to roughly 20000 per dose and overlaying with means of the data for each dose level results in this figure:

[image]

Red: the fit Hill equation, blue the means of the "true" function which is used for the sampling generation procedure. The fit matches nicely with the means of the levels, but why does it so much not coincide with the generating function?

Comment: For an extremely large sample size the two should indeed conincide, but for any finite sample size a realization may deviate from the true curve. Can you add the means at each of the doses to the plot? That will give you an idea of whether the fitted curve makes sense in terms of the particular realization of the data you are looking at. Also, can you plot the two curves subtracting E0 (i.e. for the true curve subtracting the true E0, for the fitted curve the estimated E0)? That is often a good way of looking at this type of data.

Comment: Appreciate the input, will assess.